# Where can I find mature user-created campaigns for Battle for Wesnoth?

Tags: battle-for-wesnoth

I can download user-created campaigns from the extension-server, but the quality is varying. I'd like to find a list of campaigns that are **complete**, mostly **free of errors** and **playable**.

I don't want to download a campaign, play through 3 scenarios and then have to see, that the campaign is incomplete (no other scenarios, but the storyline hasn't ended yet), or some bug make it impossible to progress further.

Comment: Asking for recommendations is pretty subjective, so might get closed here. However, a better question is probably whether there's any place which ranks campaigns by quality / popularity, or any sort of existing recommendation engine for campaigns.

Comment: I think, most of it hasn't to be subjective. If a campaign is incomplete, has many errors or incomplete/not matching graphics it is not the same quality as more matured campaigns. Problem is, I cannot see the matureness on the listing as I want it download. That's why I asked for high-quality campaigns.

Comment: I see, point taken. Maybe you should edit your question to clarify what exactly you mean by quality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you look at some of the Imperial Era Campaigns which are of good quality.

There's also the [dedicated forums for user-created campaigns on the Wesnoth forums](http://forums.wesnoth.org/viewforum.php?f=8) on which you can have direct opinion form the players and updates on new and upcoming content for customized campaigns and scenarios. :)

Comment: The Imperial Era Campaigns link is now dead, so I have removed it. If anyone has a new link for the campaigns, feel free to add it.

Answer (score -1):

Simply by just connecting to the Add-ons functionality...

[image: https://frupic.frubar.net/shots/38497.png]
(https://frupic.frubar.net/38497)

... blindly accepting whatever comes by default in the choice for add-ons service...

[image: https://frupic.frubar.net/shots/38498.png]
(https://frupic.frubar.net/38498)

... functionality will just pop up like this...

[image: https://frupic.frubar.net/shots/38499.png]
(https://frupic.frubar.net/38499)

... finally choose "Campaign" as "type", then sort by "Download count".

[image: https://frupic.frubar.net/shots/38500.png]
(https://frupic.frubar.net/38500)

Comment: That just means that it's been downloaded a lot, not that it's complete or high quality.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. Popularity (which is what downloads measure) is not guarantee that the campaing is complete.

Comment: As there is no guarantee nor the possibility to guarantee, is the actual most near proxy.

Comment: BTW. Right now some of the most _mature_ campaigns of version 12 didn't seem to made it to version 14. However provision by Steam makes mandatory to be at most recent stable (ATTOW version 14).

Comment: At the other extreme, gamers wanting extremely _mature_ campaigns (even if that means to coexist different releases of the game in a single host) they could very well want to provision version 12 _extra_ Steam to access them. For version 12 the contents of the screen shots I posted would be likely very very different.